# what is wrong with this sql query using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am writing an sql query using pivot and I am getting following errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

and query I have written is :

```
select * 
from (
        select a.ID as id,
            a.dataValue as value
        from dbo.TableA a (nolock)
        where a.ID in (select b.ID from dbo.TableB b(nolock))
            and a.someOtherId = '4000'
            and a.DT = '2/16/2011 12:00:00'
    )as data
    pivot
    (
        sum([value])
        for [id] in (select ID from dbo.TableB (nolock))
    ) as pvt
```

Can anyone help me out on this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)'s docs, you cannot use `select` after `in`: you must list the values manually.

```
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```

Assuming that `select b.ID from dbo.TableB b(nolock)` returns `1`,`2`,`3`, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
select * 
from (
    select a.ID as id,
        a.dataValue as value
    from dbo.TableA a (nolock)
    where a.ID in (1,2,3)
        and a.someOtherId = '4000'
        and a.DT = '2/16/2011 12:00:00'
)as data
pivot
(
    sum([value])
    for [id] in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pvt
```

Comment: @dashblinkenlight: thanks for the reply. I was also of the same thought. But jusr want to confirm. I am doing this because in tableB there are 100 items and writing 100 columns is bit tedious. Can you suggest something??

Comment: @Ankur Unless using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure looks particularly appealing to you (which I doubt), there's little you can do to fix this problem: SQL server does not "understand" any other syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically build the list of fields in the for in clause.

```
 for [id] in (select ID from dbo.TableB (nolock))
```

This is not allowed. You must explicitly list the column names (Sorry)

Change: select ID from dbo.TableB
To: (Field1, field2, Field3)  -- the actual names of the fields you want to return

[Example:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```